# Bootstrapping two datasets in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
 seed(1) 
 X <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2000), nrow=10))
```

where the rows represent the genes and the columns are the genotypes.

For each round of bootstrapping (`n=1000`), genotypes should be selected at random without replacement from this dataset (`X`) and form two groups of datasets (`X'` should have 5 genotypes and `Y'` should have 5 genotypes). Basically, in the end I will have thousand such datasets `X'` and `Y'` which will contain 5 random genotypes each from the full expression dataset.

I tried using `replicate` and `apply` but did not work.

```
B <- 1000
replicate(B, apply(X, 2, sample, replace = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might make more sense for you to first select the column numbers, 10 from 200 without replacement (five for each X' and Y'):

```
colnums_boot <- replicate(1000,sample.int(200,10))
```

From there, as you evaluate each iteration, i from 1 to 1000, you can grab

```
Xprime <- X[,colnums_boot[1:5,i]]
Yprime <- X[,colnums_boot[6:10,i]]
```

This saves you from making a 3-dimensional `array` (the generalization of `matrix` in R).

Also, if speed is a concern, I think it would be much faster to leave X as a matrix instead of a data frame. Maybe someone else can comment on that.

EDIT: Here's a way to grab them all up-front (in a pair of three-dimensional arrays):

```
Z <- as.matrix(X)
Xprimes <- array(,dim=c(10,5,1000))
Xprimes[] <- Z[,colnums_boot[1:5,]]

Yprimes <- array(,dim=c(10,5,1000))
Yprimes[] <- Z[,colnums_boot[6:10,]]
```

Comment: @user2294316 I've added something to my answer illustrating how to store the data sets. `Xprimes[,,i]` and `Yprimes[,,i]` contain the `i`th data set now.